# Aligning linear layouts inside linear layout like whatsapp change profile picture

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I am trying to design bottom modal sheet which will be displayed to user when they click to add / update profile picture like WhatsApp.
For that - i have coded like below in xml file.

But - i am unable to align second child LinearLayout (Gallery) at center and last LinearLayout (Remove) at right.

I've used gravity and layout_gravtiy = "center" / "center_horizontal". 
But - the result was not as expected.

What is the best approach?

**NOTE : Child Linear layouts width and height should be wrap_content.**

Thanks in advance.

Below is my xml file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:paddingBottom="10dp"
  android:paddingTop="10dp"
  android:paddingLeft="10dp"
  android:paddingRight="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Camera"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gallery"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="Gallery"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_delete" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="Remove"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the design i've approached

[image: Design approached]

**Expected design is -** : Same as Whatsapp Change profile picture dialog from bottom of screen in ANDROID.

Comment: show what you have achieved and what you want to achieve

Comment: use constraint layout for better laying out your widgets

Comment: @ShivamOberoi - Please check my modified question.

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh - Can't we do it with Linearlayout? I just want to know. I knew that we can use Constraint layout for better UI. But this screen only displays in dialog (BottomSheet)

Comment: yes, we can do it with Linear Layout as well, but why this is important if we have the better solution available, what you think?

Comment: I have updated my answer, with both linear and constraint, choose what you like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use constraint layout then your layout could be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout45"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.silverskysoft.skysalon.customViews.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
    android:layout_width="52dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Camera"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/circleImageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/circleImageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circleImageView" />


<com.silverskysoft.skysalon.customViews.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImageView2"
    android:layout_width="51dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_packages"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/circleImageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/circleImageView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Gallery"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/circleImageView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/circleImageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circleImageView2" />


<com.silverskysoft.skysalon.customViews.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImageView3"
    android:layout_width="52dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_signout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/circleImageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/circleImageView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Remove"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/circleImageView3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/circleImageView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circleImageView3" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

With linear layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout45"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/camera"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:text="Camera"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Gallery"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/gallery"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/image_delete"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Remove"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for your answer on Constraint layout. I am using it now. Thank you

Comment: Please except the answer in that case

Answer (score -1):

*Hello for your this design problem you can use bottom Sheet.*

**What is BottomSheet?**

Ans. Android Bottom Sheet component slides up from the bottom showing more relevant content. You can notice bottom sheets in apps like map apps (bottom sheet reveals the location, directions information), music players (Play bar sticks to the bottom and opens when swiping up). The bottom sheet is the component of the android design support library.

Please refer this [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/) for your solution.

Special thanks to Mr. Ravi Tamada for this awesome tutorial about bottom sheet

[Android Working with Bottom Sheet](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing link. Even i had a look into his blog on Bottomsheet which i have used before. But he has designed modal sheet vertically. I need that horizontally.

Comment: Anyhow -  i am using @Lakhwinder Singh answer on using Constraint Layout since i don't have time. Thank you.